# Can't Seem to Install Fbprophet on ubuntu 20.04 visual studio code

Tags: python, pip, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am trying to install the fbprophet library on ubuntu 20.04 for performing time-series analysis and foreacsting on a particular dataset on visual studio code as i want to deploy this model using FastAPI.

However when trying to install the library it freezes at the point where it is building the wheels for it.

What could be the problem?

PS:I have already installed the necessary dependencies (GCC,G++,make,Build-essential,python3-dev,upgraded pip,pystan and other required libraries)[image: Screenshot of the freezing process]

Comment: Please post any terminal output as text. And why not let it sit for a while? It might seem like it's stuck, but it's probably not.

Comment: i understand @Julia but it will get to a point where the machine will eventually freeze or start slowing down drastically

Answer (score 0):

I my initial troubles running prophet were solved installing python3-distutils:

sudo apt install python3-distutils

And I update PATH variable

PATH=${PATH}:[YOUR_HOME].local/bin

And looking into your screenshot it seems it has some version errors related to distutils in ~/.local

Comment: Thanks Luis. my machine already has python3-distutils installed and i updated the path variable, but it is still freezing

Comment: the way prophet worked for in my case, I installed all the python dependencies using the terminal, once I was able to run it, then I used Visual Studio Code for edit and debug

Comment: Thank you very much Luis, i was able finally able to fix the issue by installing fbprophet in the main terminal (bash) shell.

Answer (score 0):

i was able finally able to fix the issue by installing fbprophet in the main terminal (bash) shell.

Apparently the main cause was the fact that the building wheels for fbprophet couldn't interact directly with the GCC and G++ compilers in the Visual Studio Code terminal.